# Javascript for loop and global object

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I am trying to replace all 'number' divs according vobj object. for loop to pass values to global vobj, however, `numDiv[i].innerHTML = vobj[4];` doesn't print

```
5,
5,
5,
5,
5
```

instead it prints

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
5
```

so object loop below, but how to select the last object to use?

```
Object {0: "1"}
Object {0: "1", 1: "2"}
Object {0: "1", 1: "2", 2: "3"}
Object {0: "1", 1: "2", 2: "3", 3: "4"}
Object {0: "1", 1: "2", 2: "3", 3: "4", 4: "5"}
```

Code is here:

```
<div class="wrapNumber">
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="number">2</div>
    <div class="number">3</div>
    <div class="number">4</div>
    <div class="number">5</div>
</div>

<script> 
    var numDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("number"),
    numLen = numDiv.length,
    vobj = {};

    for(let i =0; i < numLen; i += 1){
        vobj[i] = numDiv[i].innerHTML;
        console.log(vobj);
        numDiv[i].innerHTML = vobj[4];
    }
</script>
```

[Working online code](https://jsfiddle.net/r7xd1oka/)

Comment: Because vobj[4] is not set in the first few Iterations. its set when it reaches i=4... So how can you assign it.

Comment: `vobj[4]` is undefined until the last iteration when you assign it. What's the misunderstanding?

Comment: move `numDiv[i].innerHTML = vobj[4];` this outside the for loop.. and it will work.

Comment: There is no 'I' outside the loop!
If you so want that you need another loop where you have the complete vobj set along with vobj[4] and do an assignment.

Comment: @atulquest93 No it won't, OP is using `let`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you accessing v[4] in for loop.... but it is not present for first 4 iterations. You have to create whole vobj with all keys and properties and then you can access it.

```
 <script> 
   var numDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("number"),
   numLen = numDiv.length,
   vobj = {};

  for(let i =0; i < numLen; i += 1){
     //filling vobj
     vobj[i] = numDiv[i].innerHTML;
     console.log(vobj);

  }
  //now we have full vobj... now we can access the key of that object

 for(let i =0; i < numLen; i += 1){
     numDiv[i].innerHTML = vobj[4];
 }
</script>
```

Working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/r7xd1oka/2/